# Mongoose Saving _id's as Numbers

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to save an `_id` as a `Number` as seen in this documentation:

> _id     : Number,

Taken from here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

However, when using this code, I recieve no errors when saving data to the `Model`. If I remove this line it saves without failure as an `ObjectID`

My code:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Number
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose automatically assigns an `_id` to every document you create being consistent with general MongoDB documents with an `ObjectId` by default. To change this behavior, just turn it off:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Number
},{ "_id": false });

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

So the `_id` generation is disabled by this option, and this could cause an error in a "top level" schema unless of course you define the field yourself. When you do then the type given is respected and used.

Without the option, the default is used and overrides any declaration you used in the schema. So this code now works as expected:

```
user = new User({ "_id": 1 });

user.save(function(err,doc) {
    if (err) throw err;      // but wont fail to cast type now
    console.log( doc );
});
```